# Dynamic placement Google map markers on the Oracle Apex 5.1

Tags: plsql, google-maps-markers, oracle-apex

I have a problem updating the markers on the map.

Apex 5.1 Database 11g Express Edition 11.2

In the first region I have a table with objects (name, coordinates ...). It is dynamically updated by filters from the second region.

The third region has a Static type

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

In Page "Function and Global Variable Declaration" Initialization map function. Function run when Page Loads.

```
function initMap() {
          var myLatLng = {
              lat: 10,
              lng: 10
          };
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
              zoom: 6,
              center: myLatLng
          });            
}
```

Also, I have a pl/sql block to load the page. Where select coordinates and place markers in loop.

```
    htp.p('<script>
            function placeMarkers() {');             
    FOR table IN (
    SELECT NAME, LAT, LNG
    FROM buildings
    WHERE /* filters from select list in Apex */)  
    LOOP 
        htp.p('var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: {lat:' || LAT ||', lng:' || LNG || '},
              map: map,
              title:' || NAME || '});');
    END LOOP;   
        htp.p('}</script>');
```

After loading the page, everything works great. But the filter updates only the table of buildings.

I tried to display the map in PL / SQL Dynamic Content. But it can not be updated due to Dynamic action.

Maybe someone faced a similar problem.

Comment: You can't have a region refreshed in a DA solely with calls to htp.p() which are executed on the server while building the page. You might consider trying the reportmap APEX plugin I built which supports dynamic refresh based on a SQL query: https://github.com/jeffreykemp/jk64-plugin-reportmap

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have used the plugin on my page. Everything seems to be fine, but there is one thing.

Comment: After changing the filters list and makers on the map of buildings are updated and all ok. At Page load, filters are cleaned up and the list refreshes. Map refresh does not work and, after the page refresh, displays the "old" filtered markers. How i can fix it?

Comment: If you have an item on the page that the user is changing and you want the page to remember after the page is refreshed, you need to post the new values to the database, e.g. with a Page Submit or with a PL/SQL dynamic action that sets the item state.